# extract subtring, splitting at pattern, using sed in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp3; do
    d="${f% - *}"
    if [ -d $d ]; then
        mv "$f" "$d/";
    else 
        mkdir "$d" && mv "$f" "$d/";
    fi 
done
```

---

I'm trying this:

```
$ echo "foo - bar.ext" | sed 's/\('" - "'\).*/\1/' | sed 's/ - //'
```

which gives me just "foo". I guess there is a better way...Don't hit me hard, I'm new to sed. But now, how to include it in a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.ext; do
    d="${f%.*}"
    #Extract Filename String before the " - " and write back to $d
    mkdir "$d" && mv "$f" "$d/";
done
```

Thanks in advance

*Further information:*

$f shall remain unchanged while a directory name, stored in $d, shall contain only the "foo"- part of a pattern matching "foo - bar.ext".

Basically, a list of files, following the pattern "foo - bar.ext" should be moved to directories which are named "foo".

E.g.:
foo1 - bar1.ext
foo1 - bar2.ext
foo1 - bar2.ext
--> will be moved to subdir "foo1"

anotherfoo - anotherbar.ext
--> will be moved to subdir "anotherfoo"

Comment: please edit your Q to include expected final values for $d and $f, given your "foo - bar.ext" input. Good luck.

Comment: Done, hope it's more clear now :-)

Comment: +1 for good beginner S.O. question. Just remember to include sample input, some required output, code that you've tried, and error messages that you get AND you'll get very fast help here. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq to really get up to speed. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost already. Only a three characters are missing in your code fragment.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.ext; do
    d="${f% - *}"
    mkdir "$d" && mv "$f" "$d/";
done
```

Comment: Wow, that's it? And I was examining sed all the time..Thank you, works perfectly.

Comment: if you got an solution what you can use, please, accept the answer. (click on the accept sign)